# How to fix tomcat image vulnerability?

Tags: tomcat, docker, ibm-cloud

I deploy a Tomcat image in Bluemix Containers (docker groups).
I specified the base image as the "latest".
The Vulnerability Advisors of Bluemix report the following vulnerability :

```
image registry.ng.bluemix.net/xxx/my-image:1 vulnerability results found
168 packages scanned
1 vulnerable packages
    libgcrypt20 : current: 1.6.3-2+deb8u3  fixed: 1.6.3-2+deb8u4
```

I don't know how to fix that and did not find any answer on the Internet.

Anyone could help ?

Thanks.

Comment: You may have better luck asking this question on ServerFault. StackOverflow is for software developement related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just upgrade the package at the beginnig of the dockerfile via the installed packaging tool.

**Edit**

Specification:
If it was an ubuntu base image you could just add

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y libgcrypt20
```

I am not sure which tool the bluemix base images use to install and upgrade packages.

Comment: Hello Lukas. Could you detail a little bit further please ? what do you mean by "installed packaging tool" ? Thanks.

Comment: @PhilippeH. Hello Philippe, I've updated my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Lukas, thanks a lot. That works. (at least, the package gets updated, but the VA is still not happy ;-)). But that answers my question.